# Background Image Fill on div with gradient

Tags: html, css

Following is my fiddle in which I am trying to put background image (position centered) to a div whose width is set to 100% and I want if the background width of image is 20px and and user screen is 100px then the image doesn't stretch width wise and blurry gradient part fills the area to the left and right part of the image. kindly let me know how can i do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/R6K5S/

```
#background {
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #2F2727;
  background-image: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4004/4335972718_a491a3076d.jpgimages/radial_bg.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
        height:250px;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  /* Can't specify a percentage size? Laaaaaame. */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

  /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

  /* Opera couldn't do radial gradients, then at some point they started supporting the -webkit- syntax, how it kinda does but it's kinda broken (doesn't do sizing) */
}
```

Comment: Your image like is broken

Comment: @Kirk use any xyz image you like i just wanna know how can I make the fill around the image.

Comment: as far as i understand is. you want the image in the center no matter what the width is right?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this is what you asked for, add this into `background` class

```
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

Use above line to make it blur border, it's actually a simple trick. it's not transparent it's a white blurry border, please optimize it for all browser as well.

```css
.imageclass{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

#background {
    background-color: #2F2727;
    background-image: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4004/4335972718_a491a3076d.jpgimages/radial_bg.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1); // Here you asked for blurry Edge
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
    <img class="imageclass" src="http://www.topcoder.com/wp-content/themes/tc-eoi-theme-v3.2/i/rss-small.png"/>   
</div>
```

Comment: kindly just let me know how to create gradient with blurry edge?

Comment: actually I guess I didnot explain my question well, what I have been trying to say is when the width of the image I use as my background   ends for 100% screen size as per users screen then the blurry endges appear on the remaining div background, the way you do it with `background-image: url(IMAGEURL), -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(237,237,237,1) 0%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%);`